# How do I remove the y-axis labels from a graph?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm working on a line graph using Chart.js, I need to create a graph like the image below.
My problem is how do I remove the y-axis labels and add a vertical one instead?

This is the code I have for the vertical y-axis text

```
var options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: "Normalized/Indexed Data",

      }
    }]

  }
}
```

But how do I remove the other labels (1.0, 1.5, 2.0 ...)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `ticks:{ display: false }`. [Docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-common-configuration)

```
var options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: "Normalized/Indexed Data",

      },
      ticks:{
        display: false
      }
    }]

  }
}
```